# How to control Arduino Uno using Raspberry Pi after image processing is done?

Tags: raspbian, arduino, home-automation, servo, dc-motor

I am working on a project which is basically a robot car to collect garbage after the image in front of it is determined as Garbage (image processing using Raspberry Pi). I want my car movements to be initiated after image is processed and stop just before it reaches the place where garbage is located and then arms will pick it up and keep in dustbin. I am controlling motion of arms servo and car DC motor using Arduino and I want Arduino to be automatically operated by some signal from Raspberry Pi without the need of users. How can this be implemented?

*I am also thinking of using Blynk app for user control later on if it can be done.*

Comment: thank you for telling us about your project .... good luck with it ...... please ask a question

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at serial communication. The arduino cable that you use to burn the programs can be connected to raspberry pi's USB port. Serial communication between them is possible then. Python module "pySerial" can be used for serial communication.

Use this link for reference [Arduino-Pi communication](https://maker.pro/raspberry-pi/tutorial/how-to-connect-and-interface-raspberry-pi-with-arduino)